# Media Queries not working on mobile when in second file

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, mobile

I've read through a bunch of topics here on stackoverflow to fix this problem and did not find any way to fix it just by yet.

Thats what I got:

I got a webtemplate using Bootstrap 3. Included is the following META-Tag:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Included as well are the following CSS files:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/gamebooster.css">
```

When I now use some of the xs classes of bootstrap everything seems to work fine. What I now want to do is add a padding to specific boxes and change the height of a logo only if the user is using a mobile device.

Thats why I've tried the following piece of code:

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {
.navbar .navbar-brand img {
    width: 50px !important;
} }
```

It seems to work just fine if I shrink my browser window, but when I try it out on my mobile it does not work at all. The curious part about this is: I'm using the exact same media query as bootstrap is, and it seems to work. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks,
Fabian

Comment: Try to this <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" name="viewport">

Comment: Sadly does not fix the problem. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
    -----

}
```

and dont Forget to Use Following Meta Tag:

```
<meta name="HandheldFriendly" content="True" />
<meta name="MobileOptimized" content="320" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
```

Comment: Hi Pooja, I just tried it out. It works on the browser again but not on my S3.

Comment: If you are talking about samsung galaxy s3 then its screen resolution is 1280x720 u should change your code according to this.!

Answer (score -2):

just try to use

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  width:50px !important;;
  max-width:50px !important;
}
```

Comment: Hi Sibin! Thanks for your answer. But it is no related to the only image. It's about every media query I use in the secondary file is not used in the overall design on the mobile phone.